# JavaScript closures for encapsulating data can be circumvented?

Tags: javascript, module, reference, closures, encapsulation

I always thought of JavaScript closures as a perfect way for encapsulating data, sort of making variables private. But I recently realized that this pattern is very easily broken by exploiting reference semantics:

```
function creator() {
  var x = {
    key: 3
  };
  return function() {
    return x;
  }
}

var instance = creator();

var y = instance();

y.key = 4;

//returns 4
//y is a refernce to x
console.log( instance() );
```

How do I make sure that the private part (variables defined in scope of `creator()` cannot be mutated from outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guida/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) . Following MDN example you should be able to return the same value even if set differently:

```
function creator() {
  var x = {
    get key() {
      return 4;
    },
    set key(x) {
      // do nothing
    }
  };
  return function() {
    return x;
  }
}
```

This way when you set key, the setter drops the input value and keeps the original init value.

Comment: Thank you, exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.